# VSCode Method allowed but only to /

Tags: python, html, visual-studio-code, flask

Very new to this - teaching myself Python/flask etc.
I have code trying to make my own word guessing game.  I have html code to produce a keyboard and return a clicked key.  It works fine returning to app route but crashes with "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL." if I change the return redirect from / to /goPlay in the def key() code at the end of the python code.

Here is python main code

```
""" rebuild LockUp """

from flask import Flask, render_template, request,session,redirect

from functionsLockup import pickWord,translateWord

# not needed intil lanuage select is enabled
# from functionsLockup import translateWord

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
@app.route("/")
def jailMan():
    """ start here - collect game control info from the player """
#    We need to add words in language for each language and pass over

    return render_template('index.html',newPlayer=True)

@app.route('/goPlay', methods=['POST'])

def goPlay():
    """ function starts a game with the named user """
    class game:
        """ class stores the game control and result data """

        def __init__(
                self, playerName, theWord,theLanguage,theGuessedWord,
                guessCount,maxGuessCount,wrongGuessCount,
                gamesPlayed,gamesWon
                ):
            self.playerName = playerName
            self.theWord = theWord
            self.language = theLanguage
            self.theGuessedWord = theGuessedWord
            self.guessCount = guessCount
            self.maxGuessCount = maxGuessCount
            self.wrongGuessCount = wrongGuessCount
            self.gamesPlayed=gamesPlayed
            self.gamesWon=gamesWon
            self.newGame=True
            self.keyPressed = key

    # # set up the object for this game
    thisGame=game
    # Go pick and save a word
    theWordSelected = pickWord()

    # add translation switch here
    if request.method == "POST":
        thisGame.playerName=request.form['playerName']
        thisGame.language=request.form['language']

    theWordSelected = translateWord(theWordSelected,thisGame.language)
    # and set up the blank copy of that word
    thisGame.theWord=theWordSelected
    thisGame.theGuessedWord = thisGame.theWord.replace(theWordSelected, "_" * len(theWordSelected))
    thisGame.guessCount=0
    thisGame.maxGuessCount=8
    thisGame.wrongGuessCount=0
    thisGame.gamesPlayed=0
    thisGame.guessCount=0
    thisGame.newGame=True
    # thisGame.keyPressed = session["key"]

    # now go play
    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.form['btnGoPlay'] == "GoPlay":
            return render_template('goPlay.html',theGame=thisGame)
        return render_template('goExit.html')


@app.route("/key", methods=["POST"])
def key():
    session["key"]  = request.form.get("key")
    return redirect("/goPlay")    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the keyboard code (though that might not be relevant).

```
{% block content %}
<div class="clsKeyboard">
    <form class="clsKBForm"  action="/key" method="POST">
        <!-- Numbers - for some languages -->
        <div class="clsRow clsRow0">
            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>


            <button class="clsKey" name="key">&nbsp;</button>

        </div>
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <div class="clsRow clsRow1">
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="Q" type="submit">Q</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="W" type="submit">W</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="E" type="submit">E</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="R" type="submit">R</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="T" type="submit">T</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="Y" type="submit">Y</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="U" type="submit">U</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="I" type="submit">I</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="O" type="submit">O</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="P" type="submit">P</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <div class="clsRow clsRow2">
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="A" type="submit">A</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="S" type="submit">S</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="D" type="submit">D</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="F" type="submit">F</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="T" type="submit">G</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="H" type="submit">H</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="J" type="submit">J</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="K" type="submit">K</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="L" type="submit">L</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <div class="clsRow  clsRow3">
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="Z" type="submit">Z</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="X" type="submit">X</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="C" type="submit">C</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="V" type="submit">V</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="B" type="submit">B</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="N" type="submit">N</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="M" type="submit">M</button>
            <button class="clsKey" name="key" value="P" type="submit">P</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Stuck!  Can anyone give me a hand here please??

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a route decorator for the "/goPlay" endpoint that handles GET requests. For example:

```py
@app.route('/goPlay', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def goPlay():
```

This will allow the "/goPlay" endpoint to handle both POST and GET requests.

When a GET request is made to this endpoint, the `goPlay()` function will be called and will return the appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing a `redirect` at the end of your `key` route you're changing to a `GET` request which isn't allowed on your `goPlay` route.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I am getting a better understanding here - though struggling. :)
Are you saying that @app.route("/key", methods=["POST"]) should read ['GET']?  The  goPlay route includes both. @app.route("/goPlay", methods=["POST","GET"])
I shall try again and do some more reading